Using letter for number in siunitx
I often need to use letters with some unit. How do I do that with siunitx?
\documentclass[border=2pc]
{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\qty{2}{\second}

% \qty{t}{\second}  HOW?
\end{document}


You can either

Turn off the number parser (\sisetup{parse-numbers = false})
Treat the letters a 'digits' (\sisetup{input-digits = 0123456789t})
The latter approach will still applied digit separation, etc., but may explode if you try to e.g. round!

